# How to debounce event's stream with long processing task in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm working on the app where we download a set of files and process all of them on a fly. Here is what I'm doing:

```
Observable.from(fileUrls)
  .compose(downloadAndPersistFiles())
  .compose(processPersistedData())
  .subscribe()
```

`fileUrls` is the set of files urls. `downloadAndPersistFiles` extracts data from downloaded files and persist them into a local db. It returns an event every time when I successfully downloaded and persisted file's data. Moreover, I use `Schedulers.io()` to spin up a pool of threads to download those files as fast as possible.

```
   private  <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> downloadAndPersistFiles() {
    return observable -> observable
            .flatMap(fileUrls -> Observable.from(fileUrls)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .compose(download())
                    .compose(saveToDb());
   }
```

For every successfully downloaded and processed file, I run an extra task, which is basically a set of queries against db to extract an additional data.

```
   private  <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> processPersistedData() {
    return observable -> observable
             //modified place - debounce, throttleFirst, throttleLast etc
            .flatMap(file -> Observable.from(tasks)
                    .compose(runQueryToExtractData())
                    .toList()
                    .flatMap(ignored -> Observable.just(file)));
   }
```

I'm aware it doesn't scale well, data set in the database grows so queries take more and more time.

`processPersistedData` is invoked for every event from `downloadAndPersistFiles` (it uses a pool of threads), so at some point, there are a few `processPersistedData` operations running in parallel and I want to limit it to one only.

Here is what I've tried so far:

- `debounce` with timeout - it adds an extra delay after every downloaded file and if downloading files takes less time than timeout, the stream will starve until there is a file big enough that its downloading and persisting 
  take longer
- `throttleLast` - it adds an extra delay after every downloaded file because I need to wait until time window ends
- `throttleFirst` - no delay for the first file, but I may miss a few last events - the best solution I found so far. The main problem I have here is that I can't synchronise downloading files and running queries - at the beginning queries are super fast, so I want to use a short timeout as possible, but over time they may take over 10-20s, so obviously I would like to slow down at this time. Moreover it doesn't prevent running two
- `debounce with selector` - it sounds perfect! I could use `processPersistedData` as a selector, which will debounce all events when `processPersistedData` is running and consume any new events as soon as it finished but after I've tried it `processPersistedData` ran every time - new stream `processPersistedData` like was created for every event.

Do you have any idea other ideas how this problem could be the approach? Or did I miss when I've tried `debounce with selector`?

Answer (score 0):

The `flatMap()` operator takes an additional parameter that constrains the number of parallel operations.

```
private  <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> processPersistedData() {
 return observable -> observable
        .flatMap(input -> Observable.from(tasks)
            //modified place - debounce, throttleFirst, throttleLast etc
            .compose(runQueryToExtractData())
            .toList()
            .flatMap(ignored -> Observable.just(input)), 1);
}
```

The `1` indicates that `flatMap()` will only process a single item at a time.

As an aside, where you have `compose(runQueryToExtractData())`, you might want to use `Completable` instead.

Comment: I've realised that I left a `//modified place - debounce, throttleFirst, throttleLast etc ` comment in the wrong place - it should be before first `flatMap`. I'm not sure how second `flatMap` prevents running `runQueryToExtractData` multiple times.

But thanks for `Completable` - I'll research it

Comment: You add the `1` parameter to the `flatMap` that you want to process only serially.

Comment: so you're saying after I add second `flatMap` with `1` parameter, it will prevent running whole `Observable.from(tasks).compose(runQueryToExtractData()).toList()` multiple times in parallel. To be honest I don't think it will work like that

Comment: To test out your theory, add logging statements at various points that display the thread ID.

Comment: Just checked and nope, it isn't the solution. But thanks anyway :)